# references to array of editTexts

Tags: android, arrays, android-edittext

I have an array of EditTexts called ArrayEt with 25 elements.

How can I get handles to the widgets using the findViewByID method and a for loop (their ids are strings) ?

Comment: Edittexts (or) Edittext values? Why do you need to keep Edittext in array when you can simply do findViewById with Id as parameter?

Comment: Could you be a bit more specific. What relevant code do you have now (XML and java) and what do you want to achieve with it.

Comment: By convention objects are noted with small letters so you should have arrayEt instead of ArrayEt

Comment: @ J.Maes thnx for the correction Actually I need to have 25 cells in a 5x5 table and set each of them them to display a random number. For that I have an integer array and I want to copy each of its members into these EditTexts one by one, preferably using a loop. The problem is, how do i loop through these editTexts ?

Answer (score 0):

You should probably create these editText programmatically in your onCreate method and add them to the view.

Comment: that wud be my last option setting the text-to-be-displayed for each of the 25 editTexts is somewhat tedious.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [Resources#getIdentifier()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/res/Resources.html#getIdentifier%28java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String%29), but be warned that it could be very inefficient.